# Generate Cybersource digest in Apex

Tags: apex, crypto, encodingutil, hashcode

Cybersource is asking to generate a digest from payload using byte array. However we don't have bytes in apex. I'm getting `SHA-256=k3t9b6mL4zCMDTOi7N1uLQMu9XxrjwOr5yRXnTG0G1A=` hash when I try to compute the digest, but cybersource returns `SHA-256=S7Euokf7I2meKLJOT3+zYG/yjTMsQR5mbT9fwGvueI8=` hash when I'm using their platform to generate it. Below is my code, can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? This is the [url](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/soap-developer-guides/dita-flex/SAFlexibleToken/GenerateHeader/httpSignatureAuthentication.html) for Cybersource instruction.

```
public static String generateDigest() {
        String body = '{'
                        +'"clientReferenceInformation": {'
                            +'"code": "US200025617"'
                            +'},'
                        +'"orderInformation": {'
                            +'"amountDetails": {'
                                +'"totalAmount": "110.41",'
                                +'"currency": "USD"'
                                +'}'
                            +'}'
                        +'}';
        Blob b = Blob.valueOf(body);
        String digest = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', b));
        digest = 'SHA-256='+ digest;
        System.debug(digest);
        
        return digest;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to make sure to have exact same String both in my code, and Cybersource Developer API portal. I just needed to remove spaces both in Apex, and Cybersource Developer API portal, and was able to generate exact same digest in both places. So above code works as expected.